# Recompile jpicusb.dll into a 64bit .dll

Tags: java, c++, dll, build, cross-compiling

**Background:** I need to communicate my computer (Win7 64bit) to a PIC18F4550 using the USB port. I found the [jpicusb](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpicusb/files/) library for Java, but it is compiled to work in 32bit OS. When I attemp to use it on my computer it does not recognize the jpicusb.dll file (which is needed). Some other posts on the internet say that happens because the .dll is built for 32bits OS.

**Question:** The files in the link contain the sources of the .class, .dll (I think?) and examples of how to use the .class. How can I compile the .dll source into a 64bit version .dll?

I would prefer not to use a VM to run a 32bit OS.

If you know how to communicate PIC to a PC in C or Java please tell me how to.

I've tried adding -m64 -march=x86-64 to the gcc command with no results

Some say the code makes it compile for 32bit but I don't know how that is possible.

I know *libusb* also does the work but I haven't tried it out (I wanted to completely discard *jpicusb*)

Comment: That's 12 years old and made for Borland C++ builder. I suspect that using something more contemporary is more likely to succeed.

Comment: Since you don't really want to cross-compile jpiusb anymore, your question may be closed at one point because it is now more about "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" than cross-compiling.  This being said, I would suggest to have a look at [usb4java](http://usb4java.org).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, I'll try them out. It may take me a day or two though.